# How do you create a RESTful API with Java servlets?

Tags: java, django, servlets, web.xml, url-mapping

I am trying to create a simple application using Java and Servlets.

In my app, there are users, and each one should have his/her own page.

I think the URLs for this page should look like:

```
www.myapp.com/users/john
www.myapp.com/users/paul
...
```

and so on.

In Django, there are ways to capture parts of the URL. For example, for what I would like to do above, you would create a URL entry like  `url(r'^articles/([a-z])/$', views.userpage)`

How do you do this with Java servlets, web.xml, etc?

Comment: Go through a JAX-RS tutorial, Jersey is the Reference Implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Path("/users/{username}")
public class UserResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/xml")
    public String getUser(@PathParam("username") String userName) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gilik.html

Really nice tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

Comment: Do I need a special library for this to work?

Comment: https://jersey.java.net/download.html

Comment: Is this better than Spring?

Comment: It has nothing to do with spring. I should recommend reading some tutorials.